# How to enumerate through group by data in linq?

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

[image]

This is my table structure. I need find out the closing quantity for the same store, supplier, item, pack size & size unit combination where TransactionID maximum. How can I do this in LINQ or Even in SQL?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = 
        from p in mytable 
        group p by new
    {
        p.StoreId,
        p.SupplierID,
        p.PackSize,
        p.ItemID
    } into g 
        select new { 
        TransectionID = g.Max(p => p.TransectionID), 
        ClosingQtySum = g.Sum(p => p.ClosingQty) };
```

Comment: Add `using System.Linq` http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb292667(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: It seems working, thanks. I will accept the answer in a few min.

Comment: Got it, its Max rather than MAX, I actually just coppied your code.

Comment: Its okk, btw I don't need to sum up the closing quantity, I just need to select the closing qty of the highest transaction ID. I used g.select rather than g.Sum. but its not working.

Comment: `ClosingQty=g.ClosingQty` ?

Comment: I came up with this. ClosingQty = g.Where(p => p.TransectionID == g.Max(q => q.TransectionID)).Select(x => x.ClosingQty).FirstOrDefault()